# Android Directory creation failing on internal storage

Tags: java, android

I want to create a new folder/directory called lists but it just keeps on failing, if anyone had any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() +File.separator +"Lists");

if(file.mkdirs()){
    System.out.println("Directory success");
}else{
    System.out.println("Directory failed!");
}

System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
if(file.isDirectory()){
    System.out.println("File is a directory");
    File lists[] = file.listFiles();
    String names[] = new String[lists.length];
    if(lists.length >0){
        for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i ++){
            names[i] = lists[i].getName();
        }
    }else{
        names[0] = "Create New List";
    }
}else{
    System.out.println("File is not a directory");
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? Does it show permission denied ENOENT error or something like that (EACCES)?

Comment: Remember that mkdirs() only returns true when it creates the directory, but false when it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer is completely incorrect (my apologies for that)! I believe this one is correct.

I think problem lies with the following lines:

```
File lists[] = file.listFiles();
String names[] = new String[lists.length];
if(lists.length > 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; i ++){
        names[i] = lists[i].getName();
    }
}else{
    names[0] = "Create New List";
}
```

You had just created the folder so there will be no files in it so `lists[]` won't have any size, but in your else statement you are adding an item to the `names` array even though it doesn't have a size. Removing `names[0] = "Create New List";` from the else statement should work.